# is there any method to load image from rapid api response url in android developemnt

Tags: android, api, loadimage

while loading image url from api response in android from rapid api while calling image url to show image in imageview it didnot load

```
"title": "Janmashtami Special Songs",
"actors": "",
"music": "Simrat Praksh",
"image_url": "https:\/\/1601606126.rsc.cdn77.org\/raagaimg\/r_img\/catalog\/cd\/H\/hd004247.jpg",
"album_id": "HD004247",
"song": "Yaad Kiya Na Kabhi Shyam Ko",
"year": "2019"
```

this is **response** while accessing this image url it shows error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>19DFAEAD969893CB</RequestId>
<HostId>
107wdT5uUDCcJmMxZUB3zSOo3nZcNU3cN5/sxdeyhQAWK0Lt/DYq6xBQBd3kt3bOjepC9N20gT0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad Qasim

Can you please send a server request that you sending? Hope you are passing 
RapidAPI-Key in request header

Answer (score 0):

From provided logs, it is clear that the url is not public. It needs to be resolved with some APIKey or method, for this you can refer to rapidAPI documentation.